# Change layout no internet access admob (Android)

Tags: layout, properties, admob

I want to change the properties of my layout, like the margins or the position (above, rigth of, left of..) when there's not internet access and AdMob ads cannot be shown. I don't know how to change these layout properties in my activities and set the layout to full screen. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is occurring in a LinearLayout, Set the addView layout's visibility to View.GONE

If you are using a RelativeLayout and using margins to prevent the addLayout overlapping your content, then try something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
myLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```